# How to not print everything inside a loop but make it based on decisions

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, break

so I have a question to Java. I want to print everything from the method once and not every time.
The method is called `refrigeratorInformation`.
So my question is, how do I just run the methode once and then get asked again, what I want to do next. Here is the code:

```
System.out.println("State what you would like to do with the refrigerator:");
USER_INPUT = input.nextLine();
while(true){
     if (USER_INPUT.equalsIgnoreCase("I want to close the refrigerator")){
         TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
         System.out.println("Shutting down!");
         TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
         System.exit(0);
     } else if (USER_INPUT.equalsIgnoreCase("What is the current temperature inside the refrigerator")){
         refrigeratorTemperature();
     } else if (USER_INPUT.equalsIgnoreCase("Show me some info about the refrigerator")){
         refrigeratorInformation();
     }            
}
```

And here is the methods code:

```
public void refrigeratorInformation(){
    dimension= "Width is 178cm, Height 66,8cm & length is 59,5cm";
    usage = 157;
    volume = 707.5; // in liter
    name = "Build Your Body Fat";
    weight = 63;
    try{
        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(weight);
        System.out.println(volume +" Liter");
        System.out.println("The refrigerator has a usage of " + usage + "kWh");
        System.out.println(dimension);
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
    } 
...
```

I would be pretty thankful, if you could help me out

Comment: To most programmers, "stopping a loop" and "exiting a loop" is the same thing, so you may need to change your title to make it clear what you actually want to ask about.

Comment: So basically you want that the program asks you for a new input in each iteration? If so, just move the first two lines (`System.out.println("Geben Sie...")` and `USER_INPUT = ...`) into the loop. Als Randbemerkung: dein englisch scheint gut genug zu sein, um hier zu posten, dann solltest du deinen Quellcode auch auf englisch verfassen. Es ist dann für andere wesentlich einfacher deinen Quellcode zu verstehen und es gehört zum "guten Ton", den Quellcode auf englisch zu verfassen.

Comment: omgggggg, im so... tank your rly much dude

Comment: No, please dont tank me x)

Comment: ja ich werds versuchen hab garnicht dran gedacht aber danke für die info! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stop executing the method you put the `return` statement in the end of this method, if you want to skip an iteration you put `continue` in your loop skipping one iteration. And if you put `break` your loop stops and not the method.
I believe you're looking for `break`

Read the docs [while loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

Comment: This does not answer the question. OP basically asked how to "pause" the loop and read a new user input in every iteration.

Comment: @Turing85 He asked how to stop the loop without stopping the method , or he should ask his question in clear English so people don't get confused if you feel my answer misses the question

Comment: From OP's question: "So my question is, how do I just run the methode once and then he starts me asking again, what I want to do". You do not answer questions based on their title alone. If the question is unclear, you ask for clarification instead of posting speculative answers.

Comment: @Turing85 ok, man if the answer does not help OP solve his problem so he shouldn't accept it . There are people who search according to the title and then get disappointed in mismatch and not finding the answer. So I hope my answer will help people who search according to the titles